# How can I extract the first digits from string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to use powershell to extract the first digits from a long string. How can I use regex to only get the first numbers from a string?

String 1:

```
000660007501S W RUSSELL DLC NO 41 SLY 2.5 FT OF ELY 313.82 FT OF FOLLOWING DESCRIBED PORTION OF SAMUEL W RUSSELL DONATION CLAIM`                     1000
```

string 2:

```
010454040006ALDERBROOK DIV NO 05                                                                                                                    62000   14000040
```

string 3:

```
012000012000ALEXANDER ACRE TRS S 1/2 OF LOT 38 TGW LOT 39 TGW N 45.96 FT OF E 109.23 FT LOT 40 LESS ANY POR PLTD DEVON LANE                         13000         38-39-40
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you define the "first digits" in each case? Please show desired output given the above input.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this:

```
$accountnumber = $p.Substring(0,16) -replace '\D+',''
$Parcelnumber = $accountnumber.Substring(0,10)
```

Comment: Why not split? `("010454040006ALDERBROOK DIV NO 05 62000 14000040" -split '\D')[0]`